# Respond with index.html to directory request on nginx serving rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

How can I make nginx or passenger respond with the index.html contained in the corresponding directory requested? For example I have a folder called `media` inside my `public` directory on my rails app, I want nginx to serve `public/media/index.html` when `mysite.com/media` of `mysite.com/media/` is requested. I tried setting `index index.html;` inside my server directive in nginx conf, but it stopped serving my Rails app. I guess it's really simple I just couldn't find the solution on my own.